# Why is it considered a good practice to generate private key from mnemonic words?

Tags: private-key, mnemonic

If I understand things correctly - we can use 12 mnemonic words to generate a private key. Having 2048 possible mnemonic words it means that there will be 2048^12 possible states.
Private key is 256 bit number so it will be 2^256.
I have queried wolfram alpha against difference between these two numbers and it seems that private key space is greater (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E256+-+2048%5E12) so how is that possible that it is safe to derive private key from mnemonic words?

Comment: who said so? of course using private keys is the way to go. mnemonic words are for users, for the pros - there is a private key

Comment: FYI: https://decrypt.co/32853/hacker-reveals-how-he-cracked-a-bitcoin-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [BIP 0039 specification](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) says that for 12 words you get 128 entropy bits and 4 bit checksum.

So with 12 words you get 128 bits "security" and with 24 words you will get 256 bits "security".